# Difference between "anyone" and "anyone else"

Tags: grammar

What the difference between anyone and anyone else in the following sentences? Should I leave out else?

- John loves me more than **anyone** in the world.
- John loves me more than **anyone else** in the world.
- In 20 years John has earned more money than **anyone** has done.
- In 20 years John has earned more money than **anyone else** has done.

Comment: The first two are ambiguous regarding who loves whom.

Answer (score 1):

**In your context, the two have the same meaning**. The difference only matters in certain contexts, but "anyone *else*" explicitly excludes some person or persons, who presumably would otherwise meet some description or criteria.

For example:

> A: Can anyone fix this computer?
>
> B: Cheryl knows how to do it.
>
> A: Cheryl is sick today. Can anyone ***else*** fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In both of your examples, you could leave out the "***else***" since it will be understood / implied.

in your examples, strictly speaking, you and John are included in "***anyone***", so what you are trying to say is

> **anyone**, except for the people I've already identified,

which is equivalent to

> **anyone else**

The same holds true for **everyone**.